# Pycharm output adding up when using threading

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm, python-multithreading

I was learning about Threads so I made a simple program in sublime text.

```py
import time
from threading import Thread


def func():
    for a in range(1, 101):
        print(a)


Threads = []

for i in range(25):
    t = Thread(target=func)
    Threads.append(t)

for i in Threads:
    i.start()
for i in Threads:
    i.join()
```

But after a few minutes, I started to get annoyed by the bad quality of autocompletion.
So I switched to Pycharm Edu and something weird happened with output. In cmd it was like this

```
60
60
97
68
58
59
70
71
74
95
89
68
53
92
91
92
93
99
100
89
96
```

and in Pycharm the output was

```
6545
46
47
54
76
775981

66



6555
55

608264
67
48
```

I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

`print` is in truth two distinct writes to stdout: the text, and then a newline. So `print(a)` is this:

```
sys.stdout.write(str(a))
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

If now multiple Threads write at the same time, it is similar to this:

```
sys.stdout.write(str(a))
sys.stdout.write('\n')
sys.stdout.write(str(a))
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Or, sometimes:

```
sys.stdout.write(str(a))
sys.stdout.write(str(a))
sys.stdout.write('\n')
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

So you get two numbers on one line and then two newlines.

The easiest fix is to join the strings & newline before using print:

```
def func():
    for a in range(1, 101):
        print(f'{a}\n', end='')
```

This produces the correct result.

(as to why this didn't happen in CMD: probably just luck)